# addsubview into mouseView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mouse, nsevent

I trying research how to add subview into mouse View like image below.
When mouse move then subview move follow mouse

[image]

If you have any ideas, please share me, please

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936794/using-nspoint-mouse-tracking-on-nsview) for tips on folowing the mouse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to move subviews inside a super view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788219/how-to-move-subviews-inside-a-super-view)

Comment: i can following the mouse but i want shown subview outside superView, it mean is following the mouse all screen full.